# ODATA Filter queries on LookUp columns from a SP List in Power Automate is giving me error

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup, power-automate, power-platform

When using  "Get Items", I am querying on my lookup column "Location" that comes from a column TitleLink in another list. So The ODTF Query is something like this:
Location/TitleLink eq 'Salle 1'    (Salle 1 is the value, it represents a room in french, i ammaking the flow to notify me if some books the room double)

When I submit the flow, I get an error:
One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.

What do I have to do? [This is the ODTF Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wzQT.png)

First I got the Query is not valid, after a while I found out that I have to check for the Hardcoded name of the Column, which I could find in the Url if I click on the column. But now I get the error about the Settings page.. which is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't look up the values directly. You can only use OData filters on the Lookup ID. So, you need to do the extra step of querying the value in the lookup table with 'Get Items' then do another query using 'Get Items' on the list with the lookup column, referencing the ID of the item you found in the first query, which you can grab with the expression outputs('Get_items')?['body/value'][0]['ID'] to avoid having to use a loop.